How to run multiple commands in a for loop writhin in one line in zsh (or bash)
Let's say I want to run multiple command in a for loop writhin in one line in zsh (in that case, print the item name within a directory and print it
for i in *; echo "=================="; cat $i done;

with the given code, I get the proper number of "==================" printed but I only get the last item printed with the cat command

The code doesn't run as it is right now. Please use https://www.shellcheck.net first and check for possible errors.

for i in *; { echo "=================="; cat $i }. The behavior you're seeing in zsh is decribed in the manual section Alternate Forms For Complex Commands.

bash and zsh are different languages. Please choose one or the other but not both, delete the useless tag, and edit your question if needed.

You can (almost) always just replace a newline with a semi-colon:
for i in *; do echo "=================="; cat "$i"; done;

Note that the trailing semi-colon (after "done") is not necessary.
In the bash documentation, search for "control operator", and you will find:
"A simple command is ... terminated by a control operator", which "is one of the following symbols: || & && ; ;; ( ) | <newline>"
In other words, any of those symbols can be used to delimit commands, and the ; works just as well as a newline in most contexts.
